# NodeJS Express | ReactJS component causes timeout error while testing a view using Mocha and ZombieJS

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, mocha.js, zombie.js

I have added to my Node ExpressJS app some components in ReactJS. Since I introduced these components, my tests are failing due to timeout error.

My test suites is including `mocha`, `zombie`, `chai` and `sinon`, but the first two are enough to reproduce the error.

This is the **test**:

```
// tests/home-tests.js
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';
var app = require('../index.js');
var Browser = require('zombie');

describe('Homepage Tests', function() {
  before(function(){
    server = app.listen(3002);
    browser = new Browser({ site: 'http://localhost:3002' });
  })

  it('should render title', function(done){
    browser.visit('/', function() {
      browser.assert.text('h1', 'A test page for ReactJS');
      done();
    })
  });

  after(function(done) {
    server.close(done);
  });
});
```

This is the **layout**:

```
// views/layouts/main.handlebars
<!doctype html>
<!--[if IE 8]>          <html class="ie ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>          <html class="ie ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!--> 
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Zombie ReactJS Test!</title>
  {{{_sections.page_stylesheets}}}
</head>

<body>

  {{{body}}}
  {{{_sections.page_javascripts}}}
</body>
</html>
```

This is the **view** I want to test:

```
<h1>A test page for ReactJS</h1>
<div id="example"></div>

{{#section 'page_stylesheets'}}
  <!-- ReactJS -->
  <script src="https://npmcdn.com/react@15.3.1/dist/react.js"></script>
  <script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-dom@15.3.1/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
  <script src="https://npmcdn.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>
{{/section}}

{{#section 'page_javascripts'}}
  <script type="text/babel">
    ReactDOM.render(
      <p>Hello, world!</p>,
      document.getElementById('example')
    );
  </script>
{{/section}}
```

I have reproduced the error in [this small repo](https://github.com/mberlanda/zombie-reactjs-test).

It seems that it could be easily fixed with a timeout like it follows:

```
// tests/home-tests.js
// ...
  it('should render title', function(done){
    this.timeout(5000);
    browser.visit('/', function() {
      browser.assert.text('h1', 'A test page for ReactJS');
      done();
    })
  });
```

However, this doesn't appear to be the most suitable solution. In particular, would you be able to suggest a way to run test only after the page is fully loaded (without timeouts to be set)?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Disable timeouts completely? `mocha --no-timeouts ...` (or, possibly, `this.timeout(0)` at the top level scope of your test file)

Comment: thank you for this shortcut @robertklep Actually I have already set the timeout in the second version of the code but I was wondering if there is an alternative solution not requiring to set a timeout

Comment: I don't think there is, the default for Mocha is to use a timeout, so the only way around that is to disable them completely (or adjust them to fit your tests better).